# Can I use this fork if the steerer isn't quite the right height?

Tags: fork, headset, steerer

I have this threaded fork that only reaches the top of the head tube.

I can fit the first part of the headset (see photo) but no other nuts (?).

Can I use it like this ?

[image: bicycle head tube with steerer tube reaching only the top]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use it like this?

Yes, you can use it like this.

But, if you do the top adjustable cup will loosen as you ride causing:

1. Damage to your headset bearings
2. Damage to bearing surfaces
3. Damage to the head tube. The head tube can become oval shaped so your headset cups won't fit correctly.

Don't ask me how I know :)

A fork with the correct length steerer tube is the best option. You need a different fork.

[image]
[Picture screen shot from Pintrest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/653162752202550023/)

Comment: thank you so much !
i'll probably give this a go cuz it's just a junk bike. but this info is great and i'll try to get another fork eventually

Comment: ah also, do you mind telling me where that image is from ? it's incredibly useful

Comment: @matt I added the link in the answer below the picture.